# Replace any characters within "( )" with other characters in string?

Tags: r

Apologies if the title is confusing. I'd like to replace any characters within "( )" with other characters.

So this is the current output

```
> "x(oldcharacters) y(oldcharacters) z(oldcharacters)"
```

And this is the desired output

```
> "x(newcharacters) y(newcharacters) z(newcharacters)"
```

I imagine this is a gsub job, but not quite sure with this one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `gsub` to match the `(` (escaped `\\` as it is a metacharacter to capture as group), followed by one or more characters (`+`) that are not a `)`, followed by the `)` and replace with the `(` and characters in the replacement

```
gsub("\\([^)]+\\)", "(newcharacters)", str1)
#[1] "x(newcharacters) y(newcharacters) z(newcharacters)"
```

#### data

```
str1 <- "x(oldcharacters) y(oldcharacters) z(oldcharacters)"
```

Comment: Haha damn okay, there's clearly some expressions I need to learn. Thanks for this! Very interesting case.